# Updating database on Blue J?

Tags: java, database, bluej

I'm trying to make a code where you can update the database and add a member to the chicken family. However when I print the method out below I keep getting 'No record found'. Why is this?

```
 public void updateMember(String name, float newMember)
{
    boolean notFound = false;
    if(notFound = true){
        for(Chicken a: farmYard){
            if(name == a.getName()){
                a.setMember(newMember); 
            }else{
                notFound = true;
            }   
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please search again, no records found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any db-specific problems aside, the code you posted won't do what you're expecting because you're using assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`) inside the `if` expression.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to me :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two issues here:

```
boolean notFound = false;
if(notFound = true){
   ...
}
```

The first is, as kryger pointed out in his comment, you are using a single = rather than == for a comparison. This will lead to unexpected behaviour.

The second is that you are setting notFound to false, then immediately checking if it is true. This will never enter the if statement and will always enter the else statement.